# How to increase the font size used in Mathematica menus

Tags: front-end, linux

The text used in the Front End menus is too small on my Linux computer. I want to increase its size. How can I do it?

I have Mathematica 10.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean menus you generate in your own code or do you mean the menus that *Mathematica* displays as part of its notebook interface?

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu 15.04 system Mathematica 10.2 does pick up the system settings for scaling.  I can go to System Settings -> Display, adjust the scaling with the slider there, restart Mathematica, and its fonts will be adjusted just like all other applications.

[image]

Comment: Apologies for no larger scale factor screenshots.  Something went wrong with them, but I don't want to start up Ubuntu again to re-do it.