# Changing the menu font size?

Tags: size, menu

How can one change the font size for the menu of mathematica 11.3 under linux? I looked under Core.nb but to be honest its rather above me. I joined a screen to show the problem. Thanks in advance for any helpful advice. :)[image]

Comment: Is the size in Mathematica different from the size in other applications?  I'd expect this to be controlled by your window manager.

Comment: I use Magnifier with Win 7 Pro. Perhaps Linux has this built in tool? This is just a possible work around suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution which worked for me (running Fedora v30) can be found on the [Wolfram community forum](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1266184). There, you want to navigate to the directory containing your Mathematica executable and run:

```
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1 QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.33 ./Mathematica &
```

Depending on your screens resolution you may need to adjust these values. If you're running Ubuntu then [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95962/how-to-increase-the-font-size-used-in-mathematica-menus) post might be useful.

Comment: ["Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)